# How to construct a repeating array

Tags: arrays, loops

How can I build an array given the requirements below?

for an array NxM of A(i,j):

- for A(1,1), A(1,2), A(1,3) = 1 and  A(1,4), A(1,5), A(1,6) = 0, repeat     these 6 characters for A(1,M-5), A(1,M-4), A(1,M-3) = 1 and  A(1,M-2), A(1,M-1), A(1,M) = 0.

  - for A(2,1), A(2,2) = 1 and A(2,3), A(2,4), A(2,5), A(2,6) = 0, repeat these 6 characters for A(2,M-5), A(2,M-4) = 1 and  A(2,M-3) A(2,M-2), A(2,M-1), A(2,M) = 0.
  - for A(3,1) = 1 and A(3,2), A(3,3), A(3,4), A(3,5), A(3,6) = 0, repeat these 6 characters for A(3,M-5) = 1 and  A(2,M-4), A(3,M-3), A(3,M-2), A(3,M-1), A(3,M) = 0
  - Repeat the above 3 steps for N rows

i.e for a 12x12 array

```
A = [1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Matlab preferably but mathematica would also be useful.

I am aware of the repmat function in Matlab but I'm interested in how you could build this in loops. For my end product the 'lines' of 1 values will curve hence a spatially repeating unit will not suffice.